# Unauthorized (401) listing synchronization jobs for service principal in MS Graph API

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use MS Graph API to configure Azure AD Connect Cloud Sync from these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/how-to-inbound-synch-ms-graph) but I am having trouble calling this [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) in Powershell using client credentials:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID}/synchronization/jobs
```

I can successfully call this using the Graph Explorer, but no luck using Application permission and authentication with a client secret in Powershell. I get 401 Unauthorized error. I can call other endpoints like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID}  # no /synchronization/jobs at the end
```

The application has the API permissions: Directory.ReadWrite.All and Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy (Application) The permissions has been granted by the admin:

[image]

Below is the detail of the code I use to authenticate:

```
$Body = @{
    'tenant' = $TenantId
    'client_id' = $ClientId
     'scope' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
    'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
}

$Params = @{
    'Uri' = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    'Method' = 'Post'
    'Body' = $Body
    'ContentType' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 }

$AuthResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

And this is how I call the endpoint:

```
$Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($AuthResponse.access_token)"
}
$Params = @{
     Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID}/synchronization/jobs"
     Method = 'Get'
     ContentType =  'application/json'
     Headers     = $Headers
 }
$res = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

And the error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

If I use the token from the Graph Explorer it works...
My token from Powershell decoded contains this "roles" section but no "scp" like in the Graph Explorer token:

```
"roles": [
"Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
"Directory.ReadWrite.All"
 ],
```

Full token obfuscated:

```
     {
    "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{TENANT_ID}/",
"iat": 1629836586,
"nbf": 1629836586,
"exp": 1629840486,
"aio": "{AIO}",
"app_displayname": "AppForAdConnect2",
"appid": "{APPID}",
"appidacr": "1",
"idp": "https://sts.windows.net/{TENANT_ID}/",
"idtyp": "app",
"oid": "{OID}",
"rh": "{RH}",
"roles": [
"Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
"Directory.ReadWrite.All"
],
"sub": "{SUB}",
"tenant_region_scope": "NA",
"tid": "{TENANT_ID}",
"uti": "{UTI}",
"ver": "1.0",
"wids": [
"{WID}"
],
"xms_tcdt": 1584535155
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm afraid you could try to add more app permissions and call other api for test. I used your script and call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`, it worked for me. 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMasy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution was to add the role "Hybrid Identity Administrator" to the Service Principal or the User used to call the endpoint "synchronization/jobs". For some reason this application template needed this additional role and the API Permission enough is not enough.

Comment: I found that for me, I needed this, plus the previously mentioned API permissions: Directory.ReadWrite.All and Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy, assigned twice:
1. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants
2. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/${servicePrincipalId}/appRoleAssignedTo

Answer (score 1):

I tried with same permissions that you have provided for your Service Principal with the below script and it successfully gave me the output.

[image]

```
$TenantName = "<your azure AD tenant primary domain here (ex-abc.onmicrosoft.com)>"
$clientID = "Application (client) ID of the registered App here"
$clientSecret = "client secret for the app"
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
 
$Body = @{
    Grant_Type = "client_credentials"
    Scope = $Scope
    client_Id = $clientID
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
}
$authUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"
  
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $authUri -Method POST -Body $Body

$spobject = "ServicePrincipalObjectID that was returned after you did post operation in the document"

$Headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $($TokenResponse.access_token)"
        "Content-type"  = "application/json"
    }
$apiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/$spobject/synchronization/jobs"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $apiUri -Method GET
 
$response
```

[image]

Which is same as the output I get from Graph Explorer.

[image]

**Note:** If you are using the highlighted object ID (Image 1 below) in serviceprincipalobjectID it will throw 401 error instead of that you have to go Enterprise Application and use the objectID (image 2 below) shown there .

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

As Discussed we are not able to do the above operation using client credentials for the AD2AADSync Service Principal but we can use another way to do those operations.

**We can use Microsoft Graph Powershell SDK :**

**Step-1 :**  Install the Module in powershell using below command

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph
```

**Step-2 :** Set the profile for the above module to beta as we will be using it to get the synchronization jobs.

```
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
```

**Step-3 :** Use the below script to get the values of the synschronization job.

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All","Directory.ReadWrite.All"
$value = Get-MgServicePrincipalSynchronizationJob -ServicePrincipalId "AD2AADSync_service_principal_objectId"
$value
$value.Status
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft.Graph.Applications Module | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/?view=graph-powershell-beta)

Comment: Hi thanks! When I go to the page of the second image, I don't see the same thing as you, I get a message saying "Out of the box automatic provisioning to AppForAdConnect2 is not supported today. Ensure that AppForAdConnect2 supports the SCIM standard for provisioning and request support for the application as described here. To determine if the application suports SCIM, please contact the application developer."  Is it the problem?

Comment: ohh .. @iteal, may i know if you are providing the service principal object ID that you have received while doing the post operation  or the one obtained from the portal first page?

Comment: So actually I double checked and you are right I managed to reproduce this with Graph explorer: I Post to instantiate and I get this objectId but when I list all the service principals, the id of the newly created service principal is different. So I was using the id instead of object id

Comment: May i know if after giving that object id resolves the powershell issue as well?

Comment: No it makes it worse, the Graph explorer doesn't work either now! With the ID that I get from listing all the service principals I can call
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{ID} on both setups, but only  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{ID}/synchronization/jobs on graph explorer. With Object Id, I get 400 and 401 errors on both setups

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236402/discussion-between-ansumanbal-mt-and-iteal).

Comment: Hello @iteal, Updated the answer with  a workaround for the scenario we were working ..